# How are options passed with jquery.timeline.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery.timeline.js and i initialise the timeline with the following script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#myTimeline").Timeline({       
    startDatetime: "2019-02-25 00:00",
    rows            : 5
    })
})
</script>
```

Here i can declare some options like the the number of rows.

Now i want to declare a sidebar option, as shown in the documentation https://ka2.org/configuring-plugin-options/

The sidebar, and some other options like the header or footer use the following

```
let options = [
    sidebar: [
        sticky: true,
        overlay:   true,
        list:   [
            "<label>Row Item 1</label>",
            "<label>Row Item 2</label>",
            "<label>Row Item 3</label>",
        ]
    ],
]
```

How is this passed to .Timeline()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const options = {
    sidebar: {
        sticky: true,
        overlay:   true,
        list:   [
            "<label>Row Item 1</label>",
            "<label>Row Item 2</label>",
            "<label>Row Item 3</label>",
        ]
    },
}
```

You were using arrays instead of object literals.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which are typos. Instead, add a comment referencing the type and flag to close as a typo.

Comment: Heretic, i didn't think it's a typo. I thought it's just a misunderstanding of basic JS. But duly noted :D